# Jython is not able to find the module

Tags: java, python, jython-2.7

These are the import statements:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
PySystemState sys = interpreter.getSystemState(); 
sys.path.append(new PyString("/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7")); interpreter.exec("from nltk import wordpunct_tokenize"); interpreter.exec("from nltk.corpus import stopwords"); interpreter.exec("import nltk"); 
interpreter.exec("import svm"); interpreter.exec("from svmutil import *");
interpreter.exec("from nltk.classify import *");
```

The output of S.o.p(sys.path):

```
['/home/deepak/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/Lib', '/home/deepak/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

`dir = "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` contains the nltk module, which is working fine.

`dir= "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7"` contains svm module.

Here is the output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/svmutil.py", line 3, in <module>
    from svm import *
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/svm.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ctypes.util import find_library
ImportError: No module named util
```

What do I need to do to get Jython to find the module?

Comment: show your import statements

Comment: These are the import statements:PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        PySystemState sys = interpreter.getSystemState();
        sys.path.append(new PyString("/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7"));
        interpreter.exec("from nltk import wordpunct_tokenize");
        interpreter.exec("from nltk.corpus import stopwords");
        interpreter.exec("import nltk");
       interpreter.exec("import svm");
       interpreter.exec("from svmutil import *");
        interpreter.exec("from nltk.classify import *");

Comment: please edit your question and put it in your question in a code block. it is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: from what I see above, you don't have `import util` so no wonder it cannot find it.

Comment: after importing util:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named util

Comment: the problem seems to be ctypes. do you have that library installed?

Comment: The comment section is not intended for multi-line text or code. If you have any additions or information to add, please add it as an edit to your question, and properly format it. For example, write "Edit: after importing `util`, this happens:...". Use the comments to notify people of your changes or to make short comments.

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse  yes library is there

Comment: hmm.. ok, I don't know, it seems svm.py is not finding that library.

Comment: is there any possibility that Jython version  is a problem i'm using 2.7.0?